# How does background-size relate to the element?

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, background-size

Sorry upfront if the title of my question seems unclear. I'm trying to create a tool that allows the user to click anywhere inside of an image and have a snippet of that image cut out for later use, similar to what you find on eBay or Amazon when you zoom on an image simply by hovering over it.

My approach (and please let me know if there's a better one) is to set the background image of the snippet to the image being observed. The background size must be set such that the size of the image in the snippet's background is the size of the image that's being displayed on the page. From there, I take the difference in offsets between the image container and the snippet container and use the X and Y components to set a negative background position.

The problem I'm facing is that when I set the background size to the same size of the image, the size of the background image inside the snippet is far smaller than the size of the image being observed. Any ideas?

This is what I have so far:

```js
console.log($("#snippet").offset().top - $("#image").offset().top);


$(window).click(function(event) {
    $("#snippet").css("top", event.pageY);
    $("#snippet").css("left", event.pageX);
});
```

```css
#image {
    height: 19em;
    width: auto;

    border: 2px solid orange;
}

#snippet {
    background: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CP0bGdEj_xg/maxresdefault.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -200px -10px;
    background-size: 19em auto;

    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sneakapeek.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img id="image" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CP0bGdEj_xg/maxresdefault.jpg">
        <div id="snippet"></div>

        <script src="js/sneakapeek.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Shake my head...

The parameters for `background-size` are `width` and then `height`, not `height` and then `width`.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/#article-header-id-2

Answer (score 0):

To position the background image inside of the snipped properly, you need to set the 'background-position' accordingly.

```js
$(window).click(function(event) {
                $("#snippet").css("top", event.pageY);
                $("#snippet").css("left", event.pageX);
                var offset = $('#image').offset()
                $("#snippet").css("background-position", (-event.pageX + offset.left) + 'px ' + (-event.pageY + offset.top) + 'px')
            });
```

```css
#image {
    height: 19em;
    width: auto;

    border: 2px solid orange;
}

#snippet {
    background: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CP0bGdEj_xg/maxresdefault.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -200px -10px;
    background-size: auto 19em;

    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sneakapeek.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img id="image" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CP0bGdEj_xg/maxresdefault.jpg">
        <div id="snippet"></div>

        <script src="js/sneakapeek.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave the background size alone, so it defaults to the size of the image. Instead, get the percentage of the top/left position you clicked by using `e.offsetY/X` divided by the image height/width and multiply by 100, then use that as the `background-position` for the snippet.

```js
var $snippet = $("#snippet"),
    $img = $("#image");
  
$(window).on('load',function() {
    var imgW = $img.width(),
        imgH = $img.height();
        
    $img.on("click", function(event) {
      var topP = event.offsetY / imgH * 100,
      leftP = event.offsetX / imgW * 100;

      $snippet.css({
        "background-position-y": topP + "%",
        "background-position-x": leftP + "%",
        top: event.pageY,
        left: event.pageX
      });
    });
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
#image {
  height: 19em;
  width: auto;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

#snippet {
  background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CP0bGdEj_xg/maxresdefault.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sneakapeek.css" />
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="image" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CP0bGdEj_xg/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <div id="snippet"></div>

  <script src="js/sneakapeek.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm using a different image than the one in the example. It's pretty small if it's not scaled, but it's an SVG. How would I approach this?

Comment: @Zulfe not sure, I would need to see it. that was my first time doing something like this. why didn't you use that img in your OP?

Comment: @Zulfe what I have works well for the center of the image, but seems to lose the percentage on the far edges... still looking at that....